# css media queries : conflict between desktop and newest smartphones resolutions

Tags: css, responsive-design, smartphone

As new phones have a really big resolution display (ex: 1280) I'm wondering what is the smartest way to do a CSS media query dedicated ONLY to Phones with 1280.
The issue I have is that if I do this :

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1136px) and (max-width:1280px)
```

I will include some desktop reslutions sizes and I want to have a different UI between desktop view and mobile view.

Is there any good practice/solution somewhere for this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If the difference in UI is because of the way the user will interact with the site (touch vs keyboard/mouse), then using media queries to detect resolutions is the wrong way of going about this.

Comment: The UI diff is more about content organization than features offered by the support. Some contents can be important on desktop, they don't on mobile.

Comment: That still doesn't change the fact that resolution has nothing to do with what kind of device it is (mobile, desktop, microwave, etc.).  Mobile users tend to become frustrated when presented with less features than the desktop version.

Comment: It depends what's the scope of the project and who is the target. Not sure you'd love having a mobile website with easter promoting adds while looking for your plane take off hour :) This is truly interesting to discuss but not really in this subject.

Comment: I'm certain I don't want to look at ads at all on any device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great way to target devices like smartphones would be to use `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`, e.g.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  /* Smartphone queries here */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  /* iPad queries here */
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) for mobile/tablet detection.

Comment: True but as I said @Fabrizio with newest phones, their max-device-width begins to play on desktop device width

Comment: @user1713964 Check out this instead then, if you're open to a jQuery alternative - http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

for the mobile devices just try to check `min-device-width` and/or `max-device-width`.

Another possibility is to check the pixel ratio of the device you're targeting

Comment: The pixel-ratio can help a little such as specifying retina displays. But it becomes harder to find a good way about device-width. For example we have the new Galaxy S4 with a device size of 1080 x 1920. It becomes difficult to manage combinations with max-width and max-device-width and isolate phones to PCs. I found also the handheld media type and unfortunatly not supported by most of phones on the market.

Answer (score 0):

User agent sniffing.

This is not good practice, but if you sniff for useragents serverside and serve different content (html/css/js) to the client (phone, desktop) it works.

Better you should ask yourself what features your UI is designed for, like touch, screen size etc. To detect this you can use CSS media queries and http://modernizr.com/

Comment: User agents have been misrepresenting themselves since forever and cannot be trusted *ever*.